# How to make custom string format like (yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_mobileno_Out.mp3)

Tags: java, android

I have string like

String str = "2014_10_06_10_20_55_+919200558880_Out.mp4";

I have saved this file in one folder in sd card,My requirement is

delete file if new file is not as format like (yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_mobileno_Out.mp3)

(date_mobileno_Out.mp3)

How to identify above pattern?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string where there are underscores and check out if there are the required amount of chars in each one. Then, you can further check if they are in the right format by using parseInt(); where you want an integer, and use string.equals(anotherString) if mobile no is correct.